# ¿Qué quiere decir (y de dónde viene) "dejabugo"?

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones, palabras-raras, neologismos

En una respuesta al hilo de Meta [Y tú ¿por qué no participas en Meta?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3049), me encuentro con el siguiente texto:

> [...] como en las preguntas sobre los repasos anuales del sitio, que cuando las veo siento un poco de ***dejabugo*** porque cada año me parecen igual [...]

He buscado la palabra en el DLE, pero no aparece. ¿Qué quiere decir ***dejabugo***? ¿Dónde se usa, cuál es su etimología y origen?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92457/discussion-on-question-by-walen-que-quiere-decir-y-de-donde-viene-dejabugo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vale, acabas de sacarme una sonrisa porque la palabra *dejabugo*... me la inventé yo.

Es simplemente la expresión francesa *[déjà vu](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu)* ("ya visto"), que se usa cuando una experiencia que en teoría es nueva nos produce una sensación de haberla vivido ya antes. Un día se me ocurrió pronunciarla como si fuera española ("dejabu"), y de ahí pasó a "dejabugo" por influencia del pueblo de [Jabugo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabugo), no demasiado lejos de donde yo vivo.

Suelo usarla en conversaciones con la gente que me conoce porque me parece divertida, lamento si al haberla usado en una respuesta os haya podido causar un poco de confusión. :-)

Eso sí, ahora que la conocéis pues difundidla por ahí, a ver si se hace viral y consigo meter una invención mía en el DLE algún día. :-D